# Is it possible to write a SQL statement in plain assembly language processor-level code?

Tags: sql, programming-languages, assembly, processor, relational-algebra

Just recently a friend suggested it is possible and achievable (though very difficult) to write a SQL statement in assembly code, since every programming operation eventually gets down to processor-level execution.

I did a bit of research on SQL's behaviour and although it follows relational algebra's theory and platform-independent execution, I still believe that the level of abstraction and semantics are rather distant as to even consider a way to translate a SQL statement to assembly code (a very operations/memory/resources specific set of instructions).

Perhaps you could *mimic* a SQL statement's processor operations result and try to replicate it with a pure assembly set of instructions. You would come to realise though, that you still would not be writing/translating SQL statements.

Take for instance, MonetDB's [SQL Reference](http://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/SQLreference) page, they state the following in the third paragraph:

> *"The architecture is based on a compiler, which translates SQL
>   statements into the MonetDB Assembly Language (MAL). In this process
>   common optimization heuristics, specific to the relational algebra are
>   performed."*

The SQL language however does not even allow for brute assembly instructions to be typed, whereas common languages such as C-based, and C# do allow for such typing/imports.

What do you guys think? Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything that runs on your computer can be coded using an assembly language. If a SQL database can run on your machine, then it can be coded in assembly.

It can be ridiculously hard to do though.

The SQL example you mention isn't that far removed from what happens when C or other compiled languages are translated to machine code. Modern optimizing compilers don't translate your C code directly to assembly. They use one (or more) intermediate representations that are easier to perform optimizations on. It's a multi-step process, and the actual assembly output isn't the main part of it complexity-wise.

If you look at it that way, your SQL case is not very different. You could imagine an SQL pre-processor that produces native code from the MAL given a sufficiently fixed environment (schema notably). With something like that, adding extensions to that SQL dialect to allow inline assembly (for aggregate functions for instance) could make sens. And doing all that manually (i.e. without the pre-processor itself) would be possible.

You loose all the portability and flexibility you get from a runtime SQL interpreter though, would have to recompile every time your schema changes, data-dependent optimizations become nearly impossible, etc. So the situations where this would be useful are, I believe, very limited. (Same thing for other languages that are usually run through a VM or interpreter - compiling them down to native code usually carries heavy restrictions.)

Comment: I can not completely agree about anything that runs on a computer being coded in assembly, and SQL operations and instructions in assembly language are something I have yet to see a sample of, even if only a try. Take for instance, writing assembly code for the manipulation of a video; that is something also worth considering outside the scope of an assembly set of instructions.

Comment: The only thing your CPU can execute are assembly instructions. **Nothing else.** If you have a program running on it (even in a VM), that program is just a set of assembly instructions (and some data). The CPU has no concept of SQL. It has no concept of what "video" or "audio" is (but it can have instructions that are targeted at those types of media). If it runs on your PC, it can be written in assembly.

Comment: I agree with you, and with the fact that every CPU instruction is an assembly instruction, and since every program relies on such operations then it is valid to assume that every language-independent operation will go though the assembly process. The main restriction though is the possibilities that each high-level language gives towards allowing for direct assembly instructions. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

> The SQL language however does not even allow for brute assembly instructions to be typed, whereas common languages such as C-based, and C# do allow for such typing/imports.

No, SQL does not allow this because it is a higher level language than C (or C#). In SQL, the code describes what should be done and not how, nor any details on how to do it. The implementation has to parse the code and compile it into a set or low-level instructions that do what SQL code describes.

For example, for a SELECT we have no guarantee on what the plan to access the tables will be, in what order they will be accessed, which (if any) indices will be used, what type of operations will be used for joins, if temporary tables will be used or the sorting is done in memory, etc...

So, something like this would be ill-defined and extremely dangerous to be allowed:

```
SELECT *
FROM a_table AS a
  JOIN another_table AS b
    ON b.aid = a.id
WHERE b_data LIKE 'Alex%'
          ( .CODE
                getRSP PROC
                mov rax, rsp
                add rax, 8
                ret
                getRSP ENDP
            END
          ) 
  AND a_date BETWEEN '2000-01-01'
                 AND '2099-12-31'
ORDER BY b_year
```

Comment: Thanks, this example here really adds up to the complex meaning of trying to write (or mix in) assembly instructions in order to accomplish the results of SQL statements.

Comment: @Javier: One of the problems is that a query can have different execution plans (and thus different processor level instructions) if it is executed twice, even with same server, same tables structure, same data (not a row added or altered).

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in compilation of relational queries/operations to assembler, you might want to check out this paper: http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol4/p539-neumann.pdf. In this DBMS, components of LLVM are used to produce CPU-instructions (which I assume is what you mean when you say assembler) from a query within the DBMS.

Also, even though I might be preaching to the choir, I want to make clear the MAL has nothing to do with CPU-instruction Assembler. Every single MAL-statement its backed by an implementation in C. MAL is used only (taadaa:) as an intermediate representation that is easy to optimized and interpret.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the machine executes instructions you could have written in assembly. However, I wouldn't call writing the assembly language directly doing a SQL query. SQL could be interpreted very differently... e.g. by librarians consulting encyclopediae, in contexts where raw assembly might have little meaning.

Comment: Your example is just what I meant by semantics and the context of SQL instructions. The way they are interpreted are beyond the reach of assembly operations.

Answer (score 0):

No. SQL is an abstraction that can be interpreted* by different SQL implementations with different SQL environments with different physical layouts. Maybe the layouts even change over time, as you `ALTER TABLE` and now you have a mixture of old and new tuple layouts. Also, there's more you can do with SQL than just *run* it. You can also type-check it, analyze it to see what kind of effects it has, put it in a view definition or stored procedure, etc.

Here's another way to put it. Can you "write" HTML as assembly language? Maybe you can write a program that, when executed, has the same effect as a browser rendering a particular page. But can your program be processed by AdBlock, NoScript, and whatever other filters I have installed? Anything that supports *all* of the relevant operations on HTML is going to be isomorphic to HTML itself. Similarly with SQL, and any other language. Any other data structure, in fact: a change in representation must preserve the meaning of all the relevant operations on that data structure. And languages tend to have lots of relevant operations.

(* I don't mean "interpreted" as in "vs compiled"; I mean "given meaning".)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I found the HTML example interesting as to show how it could be possible to emulate a specific behaviour, and the importance of considerations for the preservation of meanings in terms of operations. I agree by all means with your feedback. Thanks for sharing.